# Responsive design with 2 elements in a box

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm working on a design that has a box structure like this

[image: http://richpoints.com/images/box-model.png]

It's somewhat responsive but when I change the width of the browser the height of the video shrinks while #left-box height remains the same.  How can I set this up to have the height remain the same as the browser width decreases.  Here's what it looks like in the real world.

http://richpoints.com/b-path

Here is the relevant CSS

```
#box {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width:90%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color:rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.8);
}
#left-box {
    width:37%;
    height: 80%;
    position:absolute;
    left:.5%;
    top:7.25vh;
}
.video-container {
    top:7.25vh;
    position:absolute;
    min-width: 61%;
    min-height: 80%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-size: cover;
    right:.75%;
}

body, html {
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(../images/asphalt_texture437.jpg);
    transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:100%;
    color:#FFF;
    ooverflow:hidden;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Comment: what is your concern, spacing between them?

Comment: Have the same height on the video as the browser size shrinks?

Comment: `#box` has a fixed height, and the image is stretched out to 100% of that at all times (which also causes it to lose its aspect ratio). The video, on the other hand, isn't constrained by this even though you use CSS to try to stretch it (explained why at http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-video-element, scroll to the part on width/height). I can't offer a good solution to this, though I think there are some JavaScript workarounds to this. Alternatively, let the image keep its aspect ratio as well, vertically center it, and it should still look presentable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the left box as min-width and min-height and then set height and width as auto, like you did for the right box?  (or max-width, max-height if image sizes aren't set)

Comment: I did try that but with no luck.  I think I need to study up on min max for width and height.